# java.io.Image To InputStream

Tags: java, image, inputstream

I'm resizing a image and I need to return a InputStream object

```
public InputStream resize(InputStream input, int maxSize){
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
   double scale = (double) image.getWidth()/maxSize;
   Image scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance( (int) (image.getWidth() * scale), (int) (image.getHeight() * scale), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
   InputStream ret = (InputStream) scaledImage;//this is wrong cast
   retrun ret;
}
```

how can I convert a Image to a InputStream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this code for converting:

```
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null),    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
//bufferedImage is the RenderedImage to be written
Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(image, null, null);

ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outStream); 
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray());
```

Comment: sorry I wrote a misstake. What I want to convert is the scaldedImage, is a java.io.Image

Comment: @xedo: I have changed my answer. Convert you `Image` to an BufferedImage first